# unique check with Descending Indexes

Tags: oracle, indexing, unique

I need create a unique check on a table,the sql is like this:

```
alter table SAMPLE
add constraint A_B unique (A, B)
using  index 
tablespace MASCITY
pctfree 10
initrans 2
maxtrans 255
storage
(
  initial 64K
  minextents 1
  maxextents unlimited
);
```

It creat a unique index automatically,but what I need,is a index that a is asc and b is desc,just like:

```
create index A_B_Index on SAMPLE (a asc,b desc);
```

how to put my sql string?

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table MY_TABLE add constraint UK_X unique (A, B)
using index (create unique index UK_X on MY_TABLE(A asc, b desc));
```